# Plugin for wikipedia style references in WP?

Tags: links, wiki, references

I find inline links offputting to read so want to use wikipedia style foot-of-article references with incremental numeric linking to the external link reference.

I can just stick the HTML in but on the off chance is there any plugins on WP for semi-automating the process?

Comment: Did you find a plugin? If yes, could you please add a link to a site where it is used? If your plugin is not Netblog, could you please add an answer with your plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Netblog](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/netblog/) plugin seems to be what you're looking for.

> Connect posts and external resources (websites, pdf, doc, zip, exe).
>   Use Captions, Footnotes, Bibliography. Netblog is highly customizable.

Comment: This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. I just wonder whether there are newer better plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Footnotes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/footnotes/) which adds the ability to add links or notes in the code that are extracted to a References section.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.